# Once I reach the node e, what happens in the method? since on the node e, n, is reference to a null value.Where does program go after return from if

Tags: methods, binary-tree, nodes, tree-traversal, preorder

```
             a
            / \
          b    g
         / \
        c   d
       /
      e
       \
        f    



public static Node createData() {   //this is the nodes which make up the tree structure
    
Node a = new Node( "a");
Node b = new Node( "b");
Node c = new Node( "c");
Node d = new Node( "d");
Node e = new Node( "e");
Node f = new Node( "f");
Node g = new Node( "g");           

a.left = b;  //this block of code connects the nodes to the specific tree should look
a.right = g;
b.left = c;
b.right = d;
c.left = e;
e.right = f;


public static void preOrderTraversal(Node n) { // method recursively traverses through using preOrder

if(n == null)

return;

System.out.println(n.value + " "); 

preOrderTraversal(n.left);

preOrderTraversal(n.right);
```

}

//I understand how a, b, c, and e are being outputted. However, once we reach the node e, n is a reference to a null value. So when we enter the method with a null value, after we enter the if statement, where exactly do we "return" to? Like where does the program sort of jump to/which line is now being looked at at this point? I am struggling to understand how the method works once n is a reference to a null value. By the way, preOrder Traversal has these 3 steps in this order: Visit Node, Traverse left, Traverse right. and then repeats recursively

Comment: Back to where `preOrderTraversal` was called. You should learn to properly indent your code - it makes it much easier to read and maintain, and much easier to follow the flow of execution.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. But then what is the value of n that is passed through the preOrderTraversal method after we return back to it? Since n is null, we enter the if statement, then we return back to the preOrderTraversal method which was called, but if im not mistaken the value of n did not change, so wouldnt we just enter the method with a null value repeatedly?

Comment: Nothing is returned. `preOrderTraversal` is declared as returning `void`, which means nothing gets returned from it ever.  Did you try stepping through the code in a debugger, which would show you exactly what happens? You've got very few nodes allocated, so you can step through every line easily.

Comment: You are not trash. Binary trees have a funny feature: to actually develop them is much harder, than theoretically understand them. Particularly if they are balanced. Most programmers I know, never implemented a balanced binary tree.